# How to add a footer to popover and make content scrollable? Using Twitter bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollbar, popover

Here is image ( what I have to do )

[image]

How to add a footer to popover and make the content scrollable? Using Twitter bootstrap 3

Comment: Man , there are too many code . I've uploaded files http://www.sendspace.com/file/s1a20g

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To create a popover with footer you must alter the popovers `template` and add some CSS to style that footer. Here I also place a button in the footer, as you have included in the drawing, but you must figure out yourself what you want to do with it.

```html
<div class="popover">
   <div class="arrow"></div>
   <h3 class="popover-title"></h3>
   <div class="popover-content"></div>
   <div class="popover-footer">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

```js
$("[rel=details]").popover({
   trigger : 'click',  
   placement : 'bottom', 
   content : 'Lorem ipsum dolor ...',
   template: '<div class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div><div class="popover-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button</button></div></div>' 
});
```

styling the footer :

```css
.popover-footer {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 18px;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
```

**make popover-content scrollable** :

```css
.popover-content {
  overflow-y : scroll;
  height: 200px;  
}
```

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/3x4yD/**

[image]

Comment: Your CSS is wrong, since you're using the exact one as the header you have to change the border properties: `border-top: 1px solid #EBEBEB; border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;`

Comment: Wrong CSS is when CSS not accomplish what you want, or give another result than intended. This was my solution, how I do it - you think the layout should be different, but the one is not more correct than the second. And I assume OP is capable of styling his or hers popover exactly as he want it.

Comment: Sarke, the right way you should've said that is "your CSS has a little mistake". The way you did it was wrong, davikondrad gave a working answer, from his point of view.